# Publishing Cognito Form

Tags: links, cognito-forms

I'm unable to publish form. None of embed code and share via Facebook, Twitter, Google+ work.

I just need to know how to get the direct link to form in order to give it to applicants.

Answer (score 1):

Keerati,
I work with the Cognito Forms Team and it is my understanding we were able to work with you directly to resolve the issue you were having.

If I am mistaken you can always fill out a bug report here https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport and we can follow up with you on the issue you were having.